# Nullpointer exception with location manager

Tags: android

I wrote the below code for getting lat long positions

```
 myLocationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService    
  (Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                  myLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();

          myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates
  (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 1, myLocationListener);

  //HERE UNCOMMENT
   latitude=myLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation
  (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).getLatitude();
   longitude=myLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation
         (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).getLongitude();
```

I am getting Nullpointer exception at the following line
     (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).getLatitude();

I am testing the code on my Android 2.1 phone with GPS enabled and I gave the following permissions in the manifest file

```
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION  
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION  
android.permission.INTERNET  
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE  
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE  
android.permission.VIBRATE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you send coordinates from DDMS? If not. Do it then envoke request for location updates, I'm sure that 99.9% you wont get NPE again for this.

Comment: How do I send coordinates from DDMS and also is it required to do that if I am running on a mobile device?

Comment: http://i53.tinypic.com/5noqac.jpg This is how you can send. If you cannot find DDMS perspective go to Window -> Open Perspective -> if you don't see DDMS then go in Other. Tada! :)

Comment: Hey I am running it on mobile device.. not on emulator.. I think we can provide those coordinates if we are working on emulator

Comment: Hmm... Are you indoors? GPS is weak when it comes requesting coordinates not from clear sky.

Comment: I suggest you to try first on emulator, as i told you before, see if it is problem with the code. I'm sure there is no problem with the code you've posted. Try on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that you *have* a last known location.  Therefore, it can come back as null.

Comment: I ran the Maps application which showed my location on Map. so I think some locations should have been cached?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with emulator then without fixing the coordinate you will get null pointer exception.To fix in emulator

goto command prompt:

type: 
`telnet localhost 5554` then press enter and then type

`geo fix lat lon` enter code here`enter` and now you will get lat lon

Here 5554 is your emulator serial number

Comment: Then you should get it in most of the cases.